# Citing a country's constitution in the OSCOLA style

Tags: citations, law

How do you cite a country's constitution in the OSCOLA style?

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 2):

While the [OSCOLA style guide](https://www.law.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxlaw/oscola_4th_edn_hart_2012.pdf) does not give specific guidance for a constitution, the [MLA guide](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_faqs.html) suggests citing constitutions using the same form as laws.

As such, I would conclude that appropriate citation for a constitution would follow the OSCOLA style guide for legislation, e.g.,

> U.S. Constitution, Article I, Section 2

Comment: This. I always cite constitutions like they are laws, as, well, they are!